# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a SQL query which returns array of integers.

```
ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<>(44);

while (result.next()){
   intArray.add(result.getInt("CNT"));     // Insert the result into Java Array List
}

// Insert the result into Java Object
dc = new DCDataObj(
       intArray.get(1), //    Datacenter          1000
       intArray.get(2), //    Zone                1100
       ..................
     )
```

I get this error when I run the code:
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 40, Size: 40`

Can you tell me where is my mistake when I use ArrayList?

Comment: ArrayLists are zero-based, not 1-based.

Comment: some other notes: you don't have to declare the size of an arraylist. you should use a for loop, with the size of the array as the limiting condition, that way you can have an arraylist of any size. getting direct positions like this will only cause you more problems like this down the road unless you can guarantee your arraylist will always be the same size

Comment: @JeffHawthorne - yes you're correct. Would you show me example how to do this?

Comment: @PeterPenzov for the first part just leave the parenthesis empty new ArrayList<>() the loop would be like (for int i = 0; i < intArray.size(); i++) { intArray.get(i); } look at Laerte's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
dc = new DCDataObj(
           intArray.get(1), //    Datacenter          1000
           intArray.get(2), //    Zone                1100
           ...
```

use

```
dc = new DCDataObj(
           intArray.get(0), //    Datacenter          1000
           intArray.get(1), //    Zone                1100
           ...
```

As `List` indexes are zero based (just like arrays and strings).

---

If I were you, I'd maybe provide a constructor of `DCDataObj` that takes a `List<Integer>` as parameter and then you can simply call

```
dc = new DCDataObj(intArray);
```

Comment: Would you show me example how I can insert the content of Array directly into Java Object?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: To do that, I'd need to see the code of the constructor you are using.

Comment: The definition would be `public DCDataObj(List<Integer> list){ ... }` I'll leave the implementation up to you.

Answer (score 6):

you have to start at index 0 not 1

```
dc = new DCDataObj(
intArray.get(0), //    Datacenter          1000
intArray.get(1), //    Zone                1100
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is using an approach like this:

```
    dc = new DCDataObj();
    for (Integer k: intArray) {
        dc.add(k);
    }
```

Then you can add elements dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to get the 41st element of an array list with only 40 elements.

Remember, like with arrays (and all indexed collection in Java) indexing starts at 0.

You should start with:

```
dc = new DCDataObj(
    intArray.get(0), ... , intArray.get(39) ...
```